# NHibernate - how to audit all fields of entity?

Tags: c#, .net, hibernate, nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate and looking for a solution that will allow me to audit changes to all fields in entity. I want to be able to create a history table for every entity i.e. Users -> UsersHistory that will have same structure as Users table and additional fields such as operation type (update, delete), userid of user that made change, etc. I don't want to define such class for every entity. I'm looking for something like `History<T>` (i.e. `History<User>`) because these entries don't belong to my domain and will only be used to prepare list of changes made to the entity. I also think that it would be better to create inserts to these tables in code rather than creating sql triggers. Basically, I just need to create a copy of record in history table on update or delete and I want the insert to be generated by NHibernate. I will also need to read records from history tables - as I said these tables will consist of entity fields and some common history fields.

I cannot find guidance on how to create such solution. All I can find is adding UserModified, UpdatedTimestamp etc. if I already have such fields on entity. However, I need full history of entity not just the information who last changed the entry.

Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is cool, open source audit trail for NHibernate called nhibernate.envers https://bitbucket.org/RogerKratz/nhibernate.envers , so you do not have to reinvent the wheel.

It integrates transparently into NHibernate, no changes to your domain model or mappings.

It's as simple as, adding the reference and call:

```
var enversConf = new FluentConfiguration(); 
enversConf.Audit<User>();
nhConf.IntegrateWithEnvers(enversConf);
```

whereas `nhConf` is your NHibernate config object.

For every change on your object a new revision is created, you can ask Envers to retrieve a revision by calling:

```
var reader = AuditReaderFactory.Get(session);
var userInRevOne = reader.Find<User>(user.Id, 1);
```

or list all revisions etc. The revision data itself can be enriched with a username, userid, timestamp etc. (whatever you can think off).

EDIT:
And it is available at NuGet: http://nuget.org/packages/NHibernate.Envers

Comment: This looks great! I'm currently testing it.

Answer (score 5):

I think the best solution is using Event Listeners:

http://darrell.mozingo.net/2009/08/31/auditing-with-nhibernate-listeners/

I wrote something similar to above (modified after finding that blog) except I store the result in XML.

e.g:

```
public void OnPostUpdate(PostUpdateEvent updateEvent)
{
    if (updateEvent.Entity is AuditItem)
        return;

    var dirtyFieldIndexes = updateEvent.Persister.FindDirty(updateEvent.State, updateEvent.OldState, updateEvent.Entity, updateEvent.Session);

    var data = new XElement("AuditedData");

    foreach (var dirtyFieldIndex in dirtyFieldIndexes)
    {
        var oldValue = GetStringValueFromStateArray(updateEvent.OldState, dirtyFieldIndex);
        var newValue = GetStringValueFromStateArray(updateEvent.State, dirtyFieldIndex);

        if (oldValue == newValue)
        {
            continue;
        }

        data.Add(new XElement("Item",
                              new XAttribute("Property", updateEvent.Persister.PropertyNames[dirtyFieldIndex]),
                              new XElement("OldValue", oldValue),
                              new XElement("NewValue", newValue)
                             ));
    }

    AuditService.Record(data, updateEvent.Entity, AuditType.Update);
}
```

Audit Service just builds add some additional data such as IP Address, User (if any), was it a system/service update or actioned via a website or user, etc.

Then in my DB i Store the XML like:

```
<AuditedData>
  <Item Property="Awesomeness">
    <OldValue>above average</OldValue>
    <NewValue>godly</NewValue>
  </Item>
  <Item Property="Name">
    <OldValue>Phill</OldValue>
    <NewValue>Phillip</NewValue>
  </Item>
</AuditedData>
```

I also have Insert/Delete listeners.

Comment: I wrote sth. similar and while testing I found out that this solution does not work for collections, components etc. so you end up writing handlers for `OnPostInsert`, `OnPostUpdate`, `OnPostDelete`, `OnPreUpdateCollection`, `OnPreRemoveCollection` and `OnPostRecreateCollection`.

Comment: There's a work-around for the collections/relationships, I can't find the blog post tho, it was in 2010 tho, was looking at it last week but haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: @Phill can you please give me a link to the Insert/Delete listeners.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for are Event Listeners (unfortunately i cannot link to relevant docs because nhforge.org wiki is experiencing NRE...).

Check [Complex NHibernate Auditing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188494/complex-nhibernate-auditing)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example of how to do this: http://www.shawnduggan.com/?p=89.

Also covered in this post: [Audit logging nhibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857234/audit-logging-nhibernate)